# Node package ( Grunt ) installed but not available

Tags: node.js, build, package, npm

I'm trying to build a [github jquery-ui library](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui) using `grunt`, but after running `npm install` I still can't run the command according to the [readme file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui#building-jquery-ui).  It just gives `No command 'grunt' found`:

```
james@ubuntu:~/Documents/projects/ad2/lib/jquery-ui$ grunt build
No command 'grunt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'grun' from package 'grun' (universe)
grunt: command not found
james@ubuntu:~/Documents/projects/ad2/lib/jquery-ui$ npm ls
jquery-ui@1.9.0pre /home/james/Documents/projects/ad2/lib/jquery-ui
├─┬ grunt@0.3.9 
│ ├── async@0.1.18 
│ ├── colors@0.6.0-1 
│ ├─┬ connect@1.8.7 
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.9 
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.5 
│ │ └── qs@0.5.0 
│ ├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3 
│ ├─┬ glob-whatev@0.1.6 
│ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.4 
│ │   └── lru-cache@1.0.6 
│ ├─┬ gzip-js@0.3.1 
│ │ ├── crc32@0.2.2 
│ │ └── deflate-js@0.2.2 
│ ├── hooker@0.2.3 
│ ├─┬ jshint@0.5.9 
│ │ ├── argsparser@0.0.6 
│ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.4 
│ │   └── lru-cache@1.0.6 
│ ├─┬ nodeunit@0.6.4 
│ │ ├── tap-assert@0.0.10 
│ │ └─┬ tap-producer@0.0.1 
│ │   ├── inherits@1.0.0 
│ │   ├── tap-results@0.0.2 
│ │   └── yamlish@0.0.5 
│ ├─┬ nopt@1.0.10 
│ │ └── abbrev@1.0.3 
│ ├─┬ prompt@0.1.12 
│ │ ├── pkginfo@0.2.3 
│ │ └─┬ winston@0.5.11 
│ │   ├── eyes@0.1.7 
│ │   ├─┬ loggly@0.3.11 
│ │   │ └── timespan@2.2.0 
│ │   └── stack-trace@0.0.6 
│ ├── semver@1.0.13 
│ ├─┬ temporary@0.0.2 
│ │ └── package@1.0.0 
│ ├── uglify-js@1.0.7 
│ ├── underscore@1.2.4 
│ └── underscore.string@2.1.1 
├── grunt-compare-size@0.1.4 
├─┬ grunt-css@0.2.0 
│ ├── csslint@0.9.8 
│ └── sqwish@0.2.0 
├── grunt-html@0.1.1 
├── request@2.9.153 
├─┬ rimraf@2.0.1 
│ └── graceful-fs@1.1.8 
└─┬ testswarm@0.2.2 
  └── request@2.9.202
```

I'm confused, what am I missing please?

Answer (score 417, accepted):

The command line tools are not included with the latest version of Grunt (0.4 at time of writing) instead you need to install them separately.

This is a good idea because it means you can have different versions of Grunt running on different projects but still use the nice concise `grunt` command to run them.

So first install the grunt cli tools globally:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

(or possibly `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli` ).

You can establish that's working by typing `grunt --version`

Now you can install the current version of Grunt local to your project. So from your project's location...

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

The `save-dev` switch isn't strictly necessary but is a good idea because it will mark grunt in its package.json devDependencies section as a development only module.

Comment: I couldn't find grunt folder path in the Path System Variables after running npm install -g grunt-cli

Comment: had to run using sudo

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try uninstall grunt and grunt-cli and then doing it again. Only works for me if I use `sudo` Thank you Tom!

Comment: Note: If you have to use sudo that's to do with how you have node setup. It's not ideal but can be fixed. [sindresorhus suggests one way](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md). I prefer to use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (node version manager)

Comment: If you're here and you hit `node not found` after running the above command and you used the package manager to install node then you also need to symlink `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node`

Answer (score 26):

Add `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/` to your `$PATH`

Comment: Thank you, adding this to my .bash_profile helped fix my issue!

Comment: adding `$HOME/npm/bin` worked for me on ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 24):

If you did have installed Grunt package by running `npm install -g grunt` and it still say's `No command 'grunt' found` or `grunt: command not found`, a quick and dirty way to get this working is linking node binaries to your $PATH manually.

On MacOSX/Linux you can add this line to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` file.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/node/HEAD/bin # Add NPM binaries
```

You probably should replace `/usr/local/Cellar/node/HEAD/bin` by the path where your node binaries could be found.

If this is **quick and dirty** to me, it's because everything should work without doing this, but for an unknown reason, a link seem broken. As nobody on IRC could tell me why this happened, I found my own way to make it (grunt) work.

*PS: This should help you make grunt works, this answer is not jquery-ui related.*

***Update 02/2013*** : You should take a look at [@tom-p's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667381/node-package-grunt-installed-but-not-available/11974634#answer-14953653) which explains better what is going on. Tom gives us the real solution instead of hacking your bashrc file : both should work, but **you should try installing `grunt-cli` first**.

Comment: See the other answer - that provides the explanation.

Comment: Can you clairfy what Cellar is here? Is this something specific to you/your installation?

Answer (score 12):

In my case, i need modify the file /usr/local/bin/grunt in line 1 ( don't make this ):

```
 #!/usr/bin/env node //remove this line
 #!/usr/bin/env nodejs // and put this line to run with nodejs
```

Edited:

To avoid problems, I created a link with the name of "node" because many other programs still use "node" command.

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node
```

Comment: Constructive downvote to dissuade anyone from manually editing packaged files. For your problem you need to `apt-get install nodejs-legacy`.

Comment: Your suggestion is one of the newest and only suggestion that worked on my brand new install of Debian Jessie.

Comment: Ok Air, but i am using OSX, i will try some thing like `brew install nodejs-leacy`

Comment: @Air thanks that was my problem. After following all the previous steps, it was unable to recognize **grunt**.

Answer (score 12):

There is one more way to run grunt on windows, without adding anything globally. This is a case when you don't have to do anything with %PATH%

if you have grunt and grunt-cli installed (without -g switch).
Either by:

```
npm install grunt-cli
npm install grunt@0.4.5
```

Or by having that in your packages.json file like:

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
```

You can call grunt from your local installation by:

```sh
node node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt --version
```

This is a solution for those who for some reasons don't want to or can't play with PATH, or have something else messing it all the time, for instance on a build agent.

Edit:
Added versions as the grunt-cli works with grunt > 0.3

Comment: Someone using docker might find it useful.

Answer (score 11):

On WIN7 I had to manually add the path to the npm folder (which contains the elusive 'grunt' file)  to the Windows PATH environmental variable.
In my case that was `C:\Users\mhaagsma\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Answer (score 4):

Hello I had this problem on mac, and what I did was

installed globally and prefix with global path

```
sudo npm install grunt -g --prefix=/usr/local
```

now 
`$ which grunt`

should out put 
`/usr/local/bin/grunt`

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The right way to install grunt is by running this command:

```
npm install grunt -g
```

(Prepend "sudo" to the command above if you get a EACCESS error message)

-g will make npm install the package globally, so you will be able to use it whenever you want in your current machine.

Comment: Note that if you do this (I just tested), `grunt` will still fail because the grunt package does not include any command line tools. You need `grunt-cli`.

Comment: apparently, you need both the local and global

Comment: global install (for command line needs), local install for "require(whatever)" type needs. So you need to do both. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Instala grunt de manera global: sudo npm install -g grunt-cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
2. Try to run grunt.
3. If you have this message:

Warning:

You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.

More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass

Used --force, continuing.

3.1. Check that you have ruby installed (mac, you should have it): ruby -v

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to `npm install package_name -g` for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've found a different way round what I was trying to do.

Comment: @AJP could you tell us how you make it works, instead of just telling us you did ? Thanks.

Comment: @rayfranco sorry I basically got round it by giving up... I think we were trying to make the jquery-ui library perhaps, so we just downloaded it, can't really remember now though...  Sorry I know that's not useful, please post back the solution when you find it.  It looks like many others have come to this page (without any success).

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to remove the ubuntu bundler in my case i used:

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby-bundler
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, part of the mystery appears to be where npm installs the Grunt.cmd file. While on my Linux box, I just had to run sudo npm install -g grunt-cli, on my Windows 8 work laptop, Grunt was placed in the '.npm-global' directory: %USER_HOME%\.npm-global and I had to add that to the Path.

So on Windows my steps were:

- npm install -g grunt-cli
- figure out where the heck grunt.cmd was (I guess for some it is in %USER_HOME%\App_Data\Roaming)
- Added the location to my Path environment variable. Opened a new cmd prompt and the grunt command ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 Add this to your Path:

```
%APPDATA%\npm
```

This references the folder `~/AppData/Roaming/npm`

[Assumes that you have already run `npm install -g grunt-cli`]

Answer (score 0):

I installed `grunt` as a development dependency. For some reason I had the `NODE_ENV` set to `production` (eg. `export NODE_ENV=production`) so when I run `npm i` what got installed were the `production` dependencies instead the `development` dependencies.

To get it fixed all I had to do was to fix the respective environment variable, so by `export NODE_ENV=development` followed by `npm i` the development dependencies installed as they should in the first place.

Probably this is a rare case but if nothing else works then it is worth checking these premises too.