# Installing npm module results in command not found

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, gruntjs

I am trying to install [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). According to [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/meeting-grunt-the-build-tool-for-javascript/) all I should need to do is run

`npm install -g grunt`

After I run this command it appears to succeed and all dependencies are installed. When I then try to run grunt, I get command not found.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You need to install `grunt-cli` globally, and `grunt` locally: `npm install -g grunt-cli` and `npm install grunt`.

Comment: Installing the grunt cli worked. Thank you. This is not documented anywhere.

Comment: It's documented on the [getting started](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) page of the Grunt website. Which is a good place to, well, start.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667381/node-package-grunt-installed-but-not-available - great answer there.

Answer (score 13):

`Rob W` already answered this. But I'll post it here to be more clear. Please Rob, if you want to answer I can remove this.

You've to install grunt-cli globally:

`sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`