# Trouble downloading yeoman yo; yo: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to install node and yeoman.  I was following this link:
http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html

After getting the errors below, I tried a bunch of solutions found here:
[Node package ( Grunt ) installed but not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667381/node-package-grunt-installed-but-not-available)

But it did not work.

I was able to do sudo npm install -g bower and sudo npm install -g grunt and sudo npm install -g yo, but only yo seems to not be able to download.

```
/Users/myname/npm/bin/yeoman -> /Users/myname/npm/lib/node_modules/yeoman/bin/yeoman
/Users/myname/npm/bin/_yeomaninsight -> /Users/myname/npm/lib/node_modules/yeoman/bin/yeomaninsight.py
yeoman@0.9.6 /Users/myname/npm/lib/node_modules/yeoman
├── which@1.0.5
├── open@0.0.2
├── colors@0.6.2
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── faye-websocket@0.4.4
├── fstream@0.1.26 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.2)
├── rimraf@2.0.3 (graceful-fs@1.1.14)
├── shelljs@0.0.9
├── request@2.9.203
├── tar@0.1.19 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7)
├── grunt-contrib-coffee@0.3.2 (grunt-lib-contrib@0.3.1)
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── html-minifier@0.4.5
├── fstream-ignore@0.0.5 (inherits@1.0.0, minimatch@0.2.14)
├── grunt-jasmine-task@0.2.3 (temporary@0.0.8)
├── requirejs@2.0.6
├── grunt-mocha@0.1.7 (growl@1.7.0, temporary@0.0.8)
├── clean-css@0.3.3 (optimist@0.1.9)
├── cheerio@0.9.2 (underscore@1.6.0, entities@0.5.0, htmlparser2@2.6.0, cheerio-select@0.0.3)
├── es6-collections@0.2.0
├── connect@2.2.2 (qs@0.4.2, mime@1.2.4, debug@1.0.2, crc@0.1.0, formidable@1.0.9)
├── bower@0.3.2 (stable@0.1.5, archy@0.0.2, semver@1.1.4, async@0.1.22, tmp@0.0.23, nopt@2.0.0, lodash@0.9.2, vows@0.6.4, glob@3.1.21, rc@0.0.8, read-package-json@0.1.13, request@2.11.4, hogan.js@2.0.0)
├── prompt@0.1.12 (async@0.1.22, pkginfo@0.3.0, winston@0.5.11)
├── grunt@0.4.0-a (dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3, semver@1.0.14, async@0.1.22, hooker@0.2.3, nopt@1.0.10, temporary@0.0.8, underscore@1.3.3, underscore.string@2.1.1, glob-whatev@0.1.8, gzip-js@0.3.2, uglify-js@1.2.6, jshint@0.7.3, nodeunit@0.7.4)
└── yeoman-generators@0.9.5 (diff@1.0.8, mime@1.2.11, cheerio@0.10.8)
mynames-MacBook:~ myname$ yo --version
-bash: yo: command not found
```

Comment: This might help https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Additional-FAQ#q-npm-appears-to-have-installed-yeoman-but-yeoman-still-gives-me-command-not-found

Comment: have you checked your path - what kind of machine are u on?

Comment: Are you on linux? /Users feels like Windows + Cygwin... if that's the case, then you shouldn't install node or npm packages over Cygwin, confirm what system you are on and I'll give you a detailed answer :P