# Bower, Grunt on Ubuntu 12.04 - command not found

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, bower, bower-install

I've installed bower and grunt on my machine but non of it works. I get `:command not found` for both.

I've placed paths to bower and grunt in .bash_profile file, like:
`export PATH="/home/user/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin:$PATH"`
`export PATH="/home/user/.node/lib/node_modules/bower/bin:$PATH"`

It feels like packages are installed correctly but it can't be found.

Npm and node is located in home/user/.node and home/user/.npm directories is this is the right place for it?

`which bower/grunt` outputs nothing

Comment: have you tried to install it globaly? npm install -g bower

Comment: @jack.the.ripper Yes I did (path: `bower@1.3.12 /home/user/.node/lib/node_modules/bower`). I still have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to remind myself of this one, to set up environment on a new machine.

As per http://gruntjs.com/getting-started, there are two steps required for installation and use of Grunt.js task runner on a given project:

1. You should **globally** install *only* 'grunt-cli', the Grunt Command Line Interface. This will put the `grunt` command on your system path. This is achieved by running `npm install -g grunt-cli`, which may require root privileges depending on your setup.
2. You should **locally** install the grunt task runner proper. This is achieved by running `npm install`, after adding the desired version of Grunt.js to your project's `package.json` file. This will install the specific version of Grunt.js described in your project's package.json, under the `devDependencies` section. This is the file used by nodejs to describe project development and deployment dependencies, among other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by adding paths to `.bashrc` file, like:

`PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin`
`PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.node/lib/node_modules/bower`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667381/node-package-grunt-installed-but-not-available#answer-11974634)