# 'Command not found" after *attempting to* install grunt

Tags: node.js, macos, gruntjs, npm, command-line-interface

To start out, I've already tried solving using the following resources:

- [Node package ( Grunt ) installed but not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667381/node-package-grunt-installed-but-not-available)
- http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
- http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-gruntjs-osx-10-9-mavericks/

None of the above worked.

I'm trying to install grunt on my Mac (running 10.10.3), and after the npm install command completes, the grunt --version command returns 'command not found'.

Here's the output of my terminal window:

```
$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
/Me/local/bin/grunt -> /Me/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /Me/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)
$ grunt --version
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

My PATH variable:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:b0VIM 7.3:/usr/local/git/bin:usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: The `install` log points to `/Me/local/` as your global [`prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix) with "binaries" placed in the `./bin` directory under that. And, `/Me/local/bin` doesn't appear in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` not the same as /Me/local/bin?

Comment: Success! Adding `/Me/local/bin` to the `PATH` variable now gives me access to globally installed npm modules (based on my current configuration) - including grunt.